# how to turn list of tuples to data frame with different scores

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples, lda

I have data like this which was the output of gensim LDA model

```
date       id   score   
1/1/2019    11  [(5,0.8), (11,0.2)] 
1/2/2019    21  [(4,0.7), (10,0.1)] 
1/3/2019    35  [(3,0.4)]   
1/4/2019    44  [(5,0.8),(3,0.5), (11,0.2)]
```

The results should like this. Can anyone help?

```
date        id  score   new_score
1/1/2019    11  5       0.8
1/1/2019    11  11      0.2
1/2/2019    21  4       0.7
1/2/2019    21  10      0.1
1/3/2019    35  3       0.4
1/4/2019    44  5       0.8
1/4/2019    44  3       0.5
1/4/2019    44  11      0.2
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please include your input data and preferred output in the text of your question, not as a picture or a link

Comment: sorry, i am newbie. take sometime to get it right format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

A better method is to use `DataFrame.explode()`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')

df = df.explode('score')
df[['score', 'new_score']] = df.score.apply(pd.Series)
```

---

You can do this with a nested list comprehension:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')

unpacked = [
    {'date': row.date, 'id': row.id, 'score': x[0], 'new_score': x[1]} 
    for _, row in df.iterrows() for x in row.score
]

df = pd.DataFrame(unpacked)
```

`DataFrame.iterrows()` returns a tuple of index and row contents for each row in the frame, so you can unpack it systematically:

1. grab a single row
2. unpack the score tuple into score and new_score
3. format it as entries in a dictionary (along with date and id) to build a new frame from
4. iterate across all rows and build the final frame

Comment: let's me change my data a little bit since my id have no pattern

Comment: @py_dust Your id doesn't need to have a pattern, have you tried the code which I posted? It worked fully for the example which I tried.

Comment: will explode() function works here. let me try your solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks pciunkiewicz for quick response. By the way,  what is underscore "_" after "for" meaning.

Comment: @py_dust The underscore simply "throws away" a variable. Since `a, b = df.iterrows()` returns two things and we don't care about the first one, we can assign it to the `_` character to denote that it is junk

Comment: @py_dust I have updated my answer to use `df.explode()` since it is a much nicer solution!

Comment: It works.  Appreciate your Help pciunkiewicz. You are amazing !!!

Comment: @ pciunkiewicz , explode() does not work for me, maybe it is the version issue. your solution works for me .